# Trying to work with tiled maps

Tags: c#, google-maps, maps

I know I am probably being dense here but I need some help.
I am working on a program that handles mapping of an area, I need to have the map be GEOref'd so I can gather the MGRS coords for any point on the map. I already have a lib I wrote that does this working with images I import one by one using upper left and bottom right coords. I then simply calculate the number of pixels and their offset from the top left and bottom right of the image.

What I am trying to do is create a dragable map like GoogleMaps or any number of other mapping systems.
Here's the kicker. The system is running on a closed network with no access to Google or any other online resource for the maps.

I have 500gb worth of map data that I can work with but the format is something I am not familiar with, a XML file with some georef data, and a truck load of files with .tileset extension. 
I assume I need to create some sort of tile stitching routine similar to what you would see in a game engine, but I have no experience with such engines.

Can anyone give me some advice or libs or directions to start researching to parse and use these tileset files and get this function going?